# Share forms authentication cookie between parent and child application IIS7 .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, iis-7, web-config, forms-authentication

i have a parent app, .Net 4.0 on IIS7 and a child app .Net 4.0 as well.

I just moved this from IIS6 machine and now the location tags (inherihitInChildApplications="false") does not seem to work.

I've read countless articles and do not understand why this is not working or how to make this work. Basically when i try and tell the modules section in system.webServer to not let Child apps inherit the parent app no longer knows about the modules.. they can't be found. So is this attribute now mean the opposite of what it use to?

The other issue is.. how do i tell the child app how to find the login page on the parent app? do i have to put a full URL in there? thanks for any help/direction

Comment: anyone? url for a tutorial or info? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to both web.configs:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="MyFormsAuthCookie" loginUrl="/YourLoginPage.aspx" protection="All" path="/" timeout="90" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <machineKey
        validationKey="(your machine key)"
        decryptionKey="(your decryption key)"
        validation="SHA1 (for example, make sure it's the same in both)"
    />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```